# Check whether a given string is palindrome using Deque

Tags: python, data-structures, queue, palindrome, deque

I have written a python code to check whether a given string is a palindrome. However, there is something wrong with the code. For every string it returns True, i.e. it's a palindrome.
What is wrong with my code?

This is my code:

```
class Deque:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def empty(self):
        return self.items==[]
    def push_back(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def push_front(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)
    def pop_back(self):
        self.items.pop()
    def pop_front(self):
        self.items.pop(0)
    def back(self):
        return self.items[-1]
    def front(self):
        return self.items[0]
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
    def at(self,index):
        return self.items[index]
def palcheck(string):
    D=Deque()
    for char in string:
        D.push_back(char)
    stillEqual=True
    while D.size() >1 and stillEqual:
        first=D.pop_front()
        last=D.pop_back()
        if first!=last:
            stillEqual=False
    return stillEqual

print(palcheck("lsknfjbdf"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pop` methods don't explicitly return anything - and therefore they implicitly return `None`.

As a result, `if first!=last:` will always do `if None!=None:`.

Simply change your pop methods to return the popped value:

```
def pop_back(self):
    return self.items.pop()
def pop_front(self):
    return self.items.pop(0)
```

Comment: OKay....It worked

Answer (score 0):

To test if a string is a palindrome it's as simple as:

```
def ispalindrome(s):
  return s == s[::-1]
```